# Airflow scheduler stuck at WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (max_threads = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to initiate scheduler and Webserver, I have no prior experience with airflow.
The scheduler command is stuck at the last line mentioned:

airflow scheduler

```
[2022-10-03 15:34:25,664] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2022-10-03 15:34:25,673] {scheduler_job.py:1346} INFO - Starting the scheduler
[2022-10-03 15:34:25,673] {scheduler_job.py:1354} INFO - Running execute loop for -1 seconds
[2022-10-03 15:34:25,674] {scheduler_job.py:1355} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,674] {scheduler_job.py:1358} INFO - Searching for files in /Users/abcdefgh/airflow/dags

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,681] {scheduler_job.py:1360} INFO - There are 24 files in /Users/abcdefgh/airflow/dags

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,681] {scheduler_job.py:1411} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,702] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 34172

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,714] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>

[2022-10-03 15:34:25,731] {dag_processing.py:758} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (max_threads = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1.
```

Comment: share airflow.cfg file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.